# Running Total based on dates when retroactive dates are sometimes necessary

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

So, I'm trying to create a query in **Microsoft Access 2010** with a running total based on dates. Let's simplify by assuming the query is based a table of financial transactions called tblT1 with three fields sorted by date:

- ID
- TDa
- te Amount

Goal: Creating a financial ledger.

I can somewhat create this running total in the query by using

```
DSUM("Amount", "tblT1", "TDate<=#" & TDate &"#")
```

The problem with this is that if there are several transactions with the same date, the matching dates will all show the same running total. The running total only updates for each change in date, not per each transaction.

One way around this WOULD BE to base the DSUM criteria on ID rather than TDate. But this won't work for me because sometimes I need to enter dates retroactively, which means I end up with older transactions having higher ID numbers than the transaction following it. Since I'm sorting by date, that excludes the ID field as an option. Is there any workaround for creating a running total that updates line by line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked it out. The solution was to create a query (Call it "Query1") based on the existing table and including a new, composite ID (named NewID) based on the date of the transaction and the existing ID (primary key). I then created a second query (Query2) based on Query1 and used this NewID as the criteria in the DSUM function. However, a few words of caution: Make sure the date is formatted as YYYYMMDD so that all dates have the same number of digits and will be sorted in chronological order. Also format the existing ID to however many digits you feel is necessary (I chose 6) when you add that to the the new date number. Lastly, you need to enclose all of it in a Val() function. Otherwise, it will show up in the query as text and may not function properly in the DSUM function.
So, here is the function in Query 2: DSUM("Amount", "tblT1", "NewID<="&NewID)

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic:

```
DSUM("Amount",
     "tblT1",
     "(TDate < #" & TDate & "#) OR (TDate = #" & TDate &"# AND ID <= " & ID)"
    )
```

If you were doing this as a query, this would look like:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.amount)
        from transactions as t2
        where t2.tdA = t.tdA and -- not sure if this is necessary
              (t2.date < t.date or
               t2.date = t.date and t2.id <= t.id
              )
        ) as running_amount
from transactions as t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that gives me #Error. I also tried creating a subquery with new ID which was a composite of the Date and ID, formatted so that it would always be X digits long but that, too, resulted in #Error.